# binomial distribution problem for statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

- A soft-drink machine dispenses only regular Coke 
  and Diet Coke.
- Sixty percent of all purchases from this machine are diet 
  drinks.
- The machine currently has ten cans of each type.
- If $15$ customers 
  want to purchase drinks prior to the machine being restocked, what is the 
  probability that each of the $15$ is able to purchase the type of drink desired ?.

I know you have to set variables $x$ and $y$ so in this case I let $x = $ # of customers who purchase coke and let $y =$ # of customers who purchase diet coke, but I don't know where to go from here exactly ?. Any help would be appreciated !.

Comment: You may want to consider this as Bionomial/Hyper-Geometric distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If there are $15$ customers, and $X$ represents the number who choose non-diet, and $Y$ represents the number who choose diet, then clearly, $X + Y = 15$, so we really only need one variable to describe the number of customers who choose a drink of a particular type.

So consider the set of all outcomes of $X$ for which there is an adequate supply of both types of drinks.  Clearly, $X$ must be no more than $10$.  But it is also true that $X$ must be at least $5$, since if $X < 5$, then $Y > 10$, which of course is impossible.

Now evaluate the probability that $X$ falls in the desired range based on the probability a randomly chosen customer selects a drink of the corresponding type.